# Integration of the derivative of radial function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

If $f(x) = q(|x|)= q(r)$ is a radial function for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then assuming that $q(r)$ vanishes at the boundary, is it a true that,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_{x_i}(x) f_{x_j}(x) dx= 0,\quad  \forall i\neq j$$
where $f_{x_i} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}?$ I tried to prove this idenity using integration by parts, but I am not sure how to use the radial assumption. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the domain of integration? When you say "boundary", what is it the boundary of?

Comment: The derivative of a radial function w.r.t. any one of its variables should be an odd function. Then the integral of an odd function w.r.t. that variable will be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly we have that

$$f_{x_i}(x) = \frac{x_i}{|x|}q'(|x|)$$

which means the integral is given by

$$\int_{\Bbb{R^n}}\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^2}\Bigr(q'(|x|)\Bigr)^2dx$$

Assuming $q'(|x|)\in L^2(\Bbb{R^n})$, the inside is dominated by $\frac{1}{2}\Bigr(q'(|x|)\Bigr)^2$ by AM-GM inequality.

Notice that the integrand is an odd function of both $x_i$ and $x_j$, thus by symmetry:

$$\int_{\Bbb{R^n}}\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^2}\Bigr(q'(|x|)\Bigr)^2dx = \int_{\Bbb{R^n}}f_{x_i}(x)f_{x_j}(x)dx = 0$$

Comment: Thanks! By similar reasoning I guess, $\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i x_j} (x) \frac{\partial f}{x_k}(x) dx =0$ for all indices $i,j$ and $k$, right?